# AWS Health Checks in private instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-route53, health-monitoring

I need to perform simple health checks to an ec2 instance that does not have access to the internet. The instance is behind another ec2 using Apache as the frontend.

I can not use an load balancer, nor give the instance access to the internet.

I looked at route53 health checks as an alternative, but it also needs internet connection.

I know I can do it by using a lambda function, but I would like to know if there is any other ( 'aws managed' ) way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

1. What are you trying to check on the instance? EC2 instances come with [status checks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html) by default for general health.
2. If you want to check something specific, you might run a script on the instance (e.g. through cron) and use AWS CLI (or a similar API) to report the metrics to CloudWatch; you can also set alarms here.
3. Why not use a load balancer for the health check and just not route any traffic to it? Make sure your security groups allow traffic from the load balancer (assuming ALB) to the EC2 instance, but you can remove any inbound access to the load balancer's security group for added security.

Comment: 1. The goal was to check the health of an application hosted inside the instance, ( sorry, didn't make that very clear ) so the status checks wouldn't be useful. 2. Seems like a good idea. Shouldn't really impact the ec2 performance and wouldn't have any big extra costs. Will try that. Maybe going the lambda way too, should be pretty cheap, and easier to manage. 3. Did not consider that option before, just seemed overkill for the task. The additional cost might be a bit much too. Thank you very much for the answer!